# ¿Cómo colocar una clase de boostrap en el formulario de Django usando def __init__?

Tags: python, bootstrap, django

Tengo una duda, quiero poner una clase de bootstrap en un select en Django, sólo que aunque en forms todas las clases las está aceptando menos  `'tecnico'`
, en otras partes del código también tengo Selects pero en este caso no lo está viendo, no sé si es porque estoy usando
`def __init__`
Alguien tiene alguna sugerencia de como puedo agregar la clase `"form-select"` a técnico

> forms.py

```
class PresupuestosManoObraForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = ManoObra
        fields = ['codigo','tecnico','horas','minutos']
        exclude = ['estimate_ids']
        widgets = {
            'codigo': forms.NumberInput(
                attrs={
                    'class': 'form-control',
                    'id': 'id__manoobra-0-codigo',
                }
            ),
            'tecnico': forms.Select(
                attrs={
                    'class': 'form-select',
                    'id': 'id__manoobra-0-tecnico',

                }
            ),

            'horas': forms.NumberInput(
                attrs={
                    'class': 'form-control',
                    'id': 'id__manoobra-0-horas',
                }
            ),
            'minutos': forms.NumberInput(
                attrs={
                    'class': 'form-control',
                    'onchange': 'convMinHr()',
                    'id': 'id__manoobra-0-minutos',
                }
            ),
          
        }
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(PresupuestosManoObraForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        technicans = Tecnicos.objects.all()
        technico = [(i.nombreTecnico,i.apellidoTecnico) for i in technicans]
        self.fields['tecnico'] = forms.ChoiceField(choices=technico)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es que en `__init__` estás sobreescriendo el `field` en esta línea:

`self.fields['tecnico'] = forms.ChoiceField(choices=technico)`

Por lo que el widget que le asignas antes ya no lo usa para nada.

Una opción que tienes es ponerlo así en `__init__`, eliminando la configuración de este campo en el `Meta`:

```
self.fields['tecnico'] = forms.ChoiceField(choices=technico, 
                                           widget=forms.Select(attrs={
                                              'class': 'form-select',
                                              'id': 'id__manoobra-0-tecnico'}))
```